# Form binding in laravel for one to many relationship

Tags: php, forms, laravel

**Company Model**

```
class Company extends Model {
    public function position() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Position);
    }
}
```

**Position Model**

```
class Position extends Model{
    public function company() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Company);
    }
}
```

*companies* table: ***id_company***, *company_name*

*positions* table: ***id_position***, *position*, *company_id*(foreign key)

What I'm trying to do is to create  a dropdown list of every company name so i can reference the id of that company so i can store it as the foreign key (company_id).

***Form for storing to positions table***

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostionController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('position', 'Position')}}
    {{Form::text('position', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Position'])}}
</div>
//Reference to the id
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::select(!!!Array generated from the Company table!!!")}};
</div>
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{{Form::reset('Reset', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I'm new to Laravel so any reference to read it would be a great help Thank you!

Comment: Your Postion model class is named `Company` and it has a connection to itself ?

Comment: @Mike Sorry my bad a typpo.

Comment: usually in Laravel you use "id" as primary key... if not you have to declare it into you model : protected $primaryKey = 'id_position';

Comment: You can make a sql request such as $companies = Company::all() and you can display them in your view using a foreach statement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
{!! Form::select('company_id', \App\Company::pluck('company_name', 'id_company')) !!}
```

Comment: This is the way i used it. But i did the pluck method in the controller and returned the view with it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify foreign key name in `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` in  second parametr.

**Company Model**

```
class Company extends Model {
    public function position() {
         return $this->hasMany(App\Position::class, 'company_id');
    }
}
```

**Position Model**

```
class Position extends Model{
    public function company() {
         return $this->belongsTo(App\Company:class, 'company_id');
    }
}
```

To get company positions:

```
{{ Form::select('name',\App\Company::find($id)->position()->get()->toArray())}}
```

Or you can  get company by position:

```
\App\Position::find($id)->company()->get()->toArray()
```

Be carefull. Don't use `get()` with only `find()` method. This will return you all rows in your table. You can use `get()` after using relation function.

Comment: Thank you about your answer. Very helpful. Anyway i used the pluck() method, but its a good thing to knoe another way how to do that.